# Is there a possibility to use a custom dto via eager fetching?

Tags: api-platform.com

Let`s say you have 2 entity classes and a DTO.
EntityA has a reference to EntityB.
You declare the DTO as output for EntityB.
EntityA has a normalization-context of 'read'.
The property in EntityA referencing EntityB has a group of 'read'.
EntityB does not have any properties with groups.
The output DTO for EntityB has a property with a group of 'read'.

Why does eager loading with api-platform not follow the output declaration?

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EntityARepository::class)]
#[ApiRespource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
)]
class EntityA {
    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public ?EntityB $refToB = null;
}

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EntityBRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
    output: DTO::class,
)]
class EntityB {...}

class DTO {
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public ?string $property;
}
```

Expected:

```
{
    ...
    "@type": "EntityA"
    "entityB": [
        {
            "@type": "DTO",
            "property": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Acutal:

```
{
    ...
    "@type": "EntityA"
    "entityB": [
        {
            "@type": "EntityB"
        }
    ]
}
```